# How to convert all png files to pdf in Bash?

Tags: bash

```
for f in find *.png; do convert "$f" "$f".pdf; done
```

This is what I have to find the png files in the directory and convert them to pdf, but I get errors. What is a better way to do this in Bash?

```
convert: unable to open image `find': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2705.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
convert: no images defined `find.pdf' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3257.
```

Comment: How does bash magically know to "execute" the find? How does bash know not to expand "\*.png"  'here' but let find see the '*' ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list of filenames you are giving to the `for` loop literally contains `find`. I think what you meant to do is give the *output* of `find`, searching for all PNG images in or under the current directory, which is

```
for f in $(find . -iname '*.png'); do convert "$f" "$f".pdf; done
```

This will not handle spaces well. A better solution is to just run the conversion from within `find` itself,

```
find "$PWD" -iname '*.png' -execdir convert '{}' '{}'.pdf \;
```

Although note that you will wind up with filenames ending with `.png.pdf`

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer to have a file with `.pdf` instead of `.png.pdf` you can use :

```
  find .  -name '*.png' -exec sh -c 'convert $1 ${1%.png}.pdf' sh {} \;
```